# Convert String to Dictionary of Lists in Python

Tags: python, string

So in my python script I have the following dictionary, except it's listed in string form:

```
{'MSVCRT.dll': ['atoi'], 'KERNEL32.DLL': ['VirtualFree', 'ExitProcess', 'VirtualProtect', 'LoadLibraryA', 'VirtualAlloc', 'GetProcAddress'], 'SHLWAPI.dll': ['PathFileExistsA'], 'USER32.dll': ['wsprintfA']}
```

I however would like to have this code as a dictionary of lists, as it clearly is. I tried the following code in orderto attempt to convert the string:

```
    try:
        dictimports = ast.literal_eval(stris)
        print(dictimports)
    except:
        print("dict convert failed")
```

However it hits the except everytime :(

So to reiterate, I would like the keys to be say 'KERNEL32.DLL', and then those keys to have the list as the contents of the values, so have a list with the values ['VirtualFree', 'ExitProcess', 'VirtualProtect', 'LoadLibraryA', 'VirtualAlloc', 'GetProcAddress'] in this instance.

Comment: i cannot reproduce this. please provide a [mcve]. Don't silence the exception either, provide the full error message including the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stris = {'MSVCRT.dll': ['atoi'], 'KERNEL32.DLL': ['VirtualFree', 'ExitProcess', 'VirtualProtect', 'LoadLibraryA', 'VirtualAlloc', 'GetProcAddress'], 'SHLWAPI.dll': ['PathFileExistsA'], 'USER32.dll': ['wsprintfA']}
```

stris is a dictionary. what seems to be the problem?

`type(stris)`

> dict

`stris.keys()`

> dict_keys(['MSVCRT.dll', 'KERNEL32.DLL', 'SHLWAPI.dll', 'USER32.dll'])

if your `stris` is a string - in which case you'd have

```
stris  = "{'MSVCRT.dll': ['atoi'], 'KERNEL32.DLL': ['VirtualFree', 'ExitProcess', 'VirtualProtect', 'LoadLibraryA', 'VirtualAlloc', 'GetProcAddress'], 'SHLWAPI.dll': ['PathFileExistsA'], 'USER32.dll': ['wsprintfA']}"
```

and you will convert it to a dict

`ast.literal_eval(stris)`

> {'MSVCRT.dll': ['atoi'], 'KERNEL32.DLL': ['VirtualFree','ExitProcess','VirtualProtect','LoadLibraryA','VirtualAlloc',
>     'GetProcAddress'],'SHLWAPI.dll': ['PathFileExistsA'],'USER32.dll':['wsprintfA']}

Answer (score 0):

You could use [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to convert the string to a dict.

> The expression argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression

`eval(stris)` will execute the executions given as string an in your case return the parsed dictionary.

But be aware of this: [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673)

Comment: they are apparently already trying to use `ast.literal_eval` and it is failing.

Comment: Additionally `eval` is highly not recommended, and it is recommended to use `literal_eval` instead, which OP is already using, which **you** state in your answer. So, why is your answer to use `eval`?